# Can't read/copy/write file Windows 7 Permission Issues

Tags: windows, file-permissions

I have absolutely no idea how this happened but one of my VM Workstation Machines all of a sudden cannot read the VM virtual disk files.

Somehow it seems that all permissions on this drive have become corrupt.

I have tried

setacl
take ownership
icacls
disabling UAC (that allowed me to browser the directory)

Absolutely nothing works.  What are my options here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one Go on start button search vm workstation and right click on it's icon and select run as administrator.